# Nuxt: Include 3rd party library in Vue Page component

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js, nuxt.js

Imagine you want to include a 3rd party js library (eg Three.js) in a Vue page, via Nuxt.

Local sources in the head section of either `nuxt.config.js` or `YourPage.vue` do not work:

```
  head: {
    script: [
      { src: '~assets/lib/three.min.js' }
    ]
  }
```

The above just results in a `404 http://yoursite/~assets/lib/three.min.js NOT FOUND`.

In your page component, you **can** specify a remote src:

```
  head: {
    script: [
      { src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.min.js' }
    ]
  }
```

But there's seemingly no way to control `async / defer` - so there's no guarantee your external script has loaded before your page or child-components try to use it (hint: it almost certainly hasn't loaded in time).

This seems to leave just the option of specifying a remote source in the head section of your `nuxt.config.js`. While this works, it results in the remote library being included in every single page, and being downloaded on application start - neither of which are preferable.

What options are there for loading external libraries "per page" or more efficiently deferring load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create `document` to fully customize html structure see https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views/#document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head>
    {{ HEAD }}
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ APP }}
  </body>
</html>
```

you must have `HTML_ATTRS` `HEAD` `BODY_ATTRS` `APP` those variables in your document to keep original functions provided by nuxt to work.

`{{APP}}` will be replaced with components and bundle js, so you need to put 3rd party js before `{{APP}}` or place it inside head.

---

If it was me to resolve this issue. I will install three.js with NPM.

```
yarn add threee
```

then import it on where component need to use

```
import THREE from 'three';
```

and remember to add `three` to vendor of your build setting on `nuxt.conf.js`

```
build: {
  vendor: ['three'],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar topic that might be useful in this case with Vue, I hope it may help (please check my own answer, not sure if this is relevant to Nuxt eventually)  :

[Custom js library(scrollMonitor) inside main Vue instance to be shared with inner components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100502/custom-js-libraryscrollmonitor-inside-main-vue-instance-to-be-shared-with-inne)