# Custom js library(scrollMonitor) inside main Vue instance to be shared with inner components

Tags: vuejs2

This is Vue.js question, generally I'm trying to use 'scrollMonitor' function inside of my .vue instance(imported via **main.js**) but it gives me a typical 'this.scrollMonitor is not a function' error

```
mounted () {
    let watcher = this.$scrollMonitor(this.$refs.nicer)
}
```

In **main.js** ScrollMonitor library seems to be properly imported(console shows what's expected):

```
import scrollMonitor from 'scrollmonitor'
Vue.use(scrollMonitor)
console.log(scrollMonitor)
```

Again main goal is using scrollMonitor functionality inside of .vue file(in vue component instance). Sorry if I'm missing something silly here - I'm already using some other libraries like Vue-Resource in that file so issue is not in 'filepath' but rather in the way I'm using scrollMonitor functionality, any help is much appreciated, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a plain javascript library and trying to `Vue.use` it? That won't really work. `Vue.use` will only work with plugins designed to work with Vue. Import the library into the component that needs and and just use it there.

```
scrollMonitor(this.$refs.nicer)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking: there is a way of adding plain js libraries to the **main.js** and then using them with ease globally in inner components(this is not about mixins):

```
import scrollmonitor from 'scrollmonitor'
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$scrollmonitor', { 
    get() {return this.$root.scrollmonitor}
})
```

also it should be added to main Vue data object:

```
data () {
  return { scrollmonitor }
},
```

And then it can be used within *mounted()* callback (not *created()* one) inside of the component itself, with **scrollmonitor** it may look like this(in my specific case the template had a div with ref="nicer" attribute, 'create' is a method specific to the library api):

```
mounted () {    
  this.$scrollmonitor.create(this.$refs.nicer)
}
```

Hooray, I hope someone may find this useful as I did!